# jquery: Count number of words in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements with data attribute containing some tags.

I need to count number of each element's tags.

like this:

```
<div data-tags="foo bar something else">
    some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo bar">
    some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo">
    some text
</div>
<div data-tags="">
    some text
</div>
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
$('div[data-tags]').each(function(){
    var tags = $(this).data('tags'),
        count = tags.split(' ').length;
    $(this).css({marginLeft: (20 * count)});
});
```

But in this way the count will be 1 for both elements with data-tags="" and data-tags="foo" since the result for split would be like this:

```
"".split(' '); //[""]
"foo".split(' '); //["foo"]
```

and length of both of these is 1.

The only way I can think of is to add a condition and do the stuff if the split result was not [""]. But it doesn't look like a good idea. Or not the best at least.

I want to know if anyone has a better idea. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regexp `match` instead of simple split:

```
$('div[data-tags]').css('marginLeft', function() {
    var tags = $(this).data('tags');
    return (tags.match(/\w+/g) || []).length * 20;
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dqfx0wun/2/

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `Array.prototype.filter()`, and `String.prototype.trim()`, to remove empty white-space-only array-elements:

```js
$('div[data-tags]').each(function() {
  var tags = $(this).data('tags'),
    count = tags.split(' ').filter(function (word) {
      return word.trim().length;
      }).length;
  $(this).css({
    marginLeft: (20 * count)
  });
});
```

```css
div[data] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-tags="foo bar something else">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo bar">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="">
  some text
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, test for the `length` of the `tags` variable; zero is a falsey value:

```js
$('div[data-tags]').each(function() {
  var tags = $(this).data('tags'),
    count = tags.split(' ').length;
  $(this).css({
    marginLeft: tags.length  ? (20 * count) : 0
  });
});
```

```css
div[data] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-tags="foo bar something else">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo bar">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="foo">
  some text
</div>
<div data-tags="">
  some text
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is great but i had to choose the right answer and @dfsq answer was very smart. I think.